# Async waterfall passing in arguments

Tags: node.js, node-async

I have a question regarding passing arguments in async.waterfall() to the third function rather than the first function. For example, as following

```
async.waterfall([
   first,
   second,
   async.apply(third, obj)
], function(err, result){});
```

Now is it possible to use the "obj" as an argument in the function named **third** and also use the arguments passed down from the callback of function named **second**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes. You can do that. see below. see the last function.

```
    var async = require('async');

    async.waterfall([
        myFirstFunction,
        mySecondFunction,
        async.apply(myLastFunction, 'deen'),
    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    function myFirstFunction(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    }
    function mySecondFunction(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    }
    function myLastFunction(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 is what you have passed in the apply function
        // arg2 is from second function
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! this should be in the lib documentation :)